# Assembly popf and rcl/rcr instructions

Tags: assembly, x86

I wonder why when I compile this

```
mov ax , 0x00FF 
push ax 
popf 
rcr ax , 1
```

I get the `807F` as the answer. I know that `popf` moves a top of the stack into flags register but how does it affect `CF`? Does it insert only first or maybe last bit of moved word?

Comment: Why didn't you consult the instruction set reference?  The least significant bit of `EFLAGS` is `CF` so yeah, it gets set from there. Depending on how you look at it, it's the first or the last bit :)

Comment: It overwrites the flags completely with what you pushed from AX.

Comment: Use a debugger. It will show you the values of the registers as well as those of each of the flags in *real time*. For best results, combine with the instruction set documentation (Google for the name of the instruction + x86).

Answer (score 1):

Prior to using `popf`, you've pushed a value that has 8 bits set. Only 5 of these *set-bits* will effectively change some processor flag.

Directly after `popf` the lowest word of the EFLAGS register look like this:

```
-- NT IO/PL OF DF IF TF SF ZF -- AF -- PF -- CF
 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  1
                               ^     ^     ^
                               These bits you are not allowed to change
```

From the diagram follows that the carry flag is now set. Since the `rcr ax, 1` instruction shifts the CF into bit 15 of the `AX` register which was still holding 0000000011111111 (00FFh), the result becomes 1000000001111111 (807Fh). The CF is still/again set because the old bit 0 from the `AX` register was put there.